# How can I cache a hbs rendered template in nodejs

Tags: node.js, handlebars.js, express

Just a simple question. If i have a very simple handlebars template in nodejs that is likely to be rendered quite a few times without ever needing to change what is the best way to cache the result to make sure it doesn't need to render the handlebars result every time.

e.g:

```
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    {{hostname}}
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Express doesn't have any native to support to cache server side, just add headers/tags to tell your clients browser to cache for x seconds so to cache server side you need to implement it yourself in each route.

I would suggest using a key/value server such as Redis or Memcached for holding the caches as they are simple and scalable if need be.

In this example I'll use an NPM module called `cachey` (full disclosure: I wrote it)

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
var redis = require('redis').createClient();
var cachey = require('cachey')(redis);

app.get("/", function (req, res, next) {
  // Arg 1: Key to save data under in Key/Value Store
  // Arg 2: Time To Live (In Seconds)
  // Arg 3: getData Function (returning via async callback "cb") This will be called if data isn't already cached
  // Arg 4: doWork Function / When the data is returned from cache or getData(), this is called providing the data
  cachey.cache("renderedHomepage", 10, function(cb) {
    cb(null, app.render("home.html"));
  }, function(err, homepageHTML) {
    res.send(homepageHTML);
  });
});
```

This example is quite pointless to be honest as it's only worth caching when it's going to take longer generating the data than receiving it from cache but hopefully it shows you the structure of how to do it in NodeJS, Express and Redis.

Cachey Links: [NPM](https://npmjs.org/package/cachey) [GitHub](https://github.com/bencevans/node-cachey)
ExpressJS Links: [API Docs](http://expressjs.com/api.html)